# How to reconnect automatically to a TCP Server?

Tags: bash, shell, tcp, telnet, netcat

I'm having a TCP-Server which prints out some logging information. Normally I'm used to dump these logging to terminal by:

```
nc -v 192.168.0.42 7777
```

Or I dump the logging to a file using

```
nc -v 192.168.0.42 7777 >> log.log
```

Well, sometimes the server runs through a reboot. Thus the connection to the client is disconnected and the logging to the file `log.log` stops.

**So I ask: How to reconnect automatically to the TCP Server?**

I tried this:

```
while true; do nc -v 192.168.0.42 7777; done
```

But this does not work. If the server does its reboot nc does not notice that the connection has become inactive.

If you would like to reproduce this scenario just open a server-terminal with `nc -l 7777` and then run the commands above within a second terminal. The server can then be terminated by `ctrl-c`.

Comment: Do you want to keep `nc` listening forever?

Comment: No, I am using nc as a client, so it is not listening.